# firebase realtime database ref (/.info/connected) how does it work

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using

```
    firebase.database().ref('.info/connected').on('value', function (snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.val() !== false) {
            console.log("connected");
        }

    })
```

To detect the presence of the users. I am trying to understand how does Realtime Database detect if a client is connected or not. It is some black magic for me now. In another words, what are the conditions for a user to be considered `true` or `false` under `.info/connected` field.

For example, I know in order to be `false`, the user can leave the page where my web app is found. But what are the conditions exactly? Does it mean if a user executes the `firebase.initializeApp(config);` codes, and that I run the presence tracking in the same file, then the user is considered to be connected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.info/connected` node returns true when the client in the app is connect to the Firebase Realtime Database backend. There's nothing more to it than that, the client/SDK simple marks the node as `true` once it's established a connection and ensures it's `false` otherwise.

This is not strictly related to presence, as this node only tell the client whether **they** are connected to the database servers. But you'd typically combine `.info/connected` and `onDisconnect` handlers to [build a system where you report your own presence, and then can see the online status of other users](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities#section-presence).

Comment: Sorry Frank, I forgot to reply to this question. I successfully built presence with the solution Firestore provided. But I am trying to understand how does the `.info/connected` detects whether a user is online or offline. So far, when the page loads up, the user becomes online, but I like to modify it to do something else.

Comment: The `.info/connected` doesn't detect whether the user is online or offline, but whether the database client is connected to the database server. To do this, it checks whether the socket that is used for communicating with the database is open. The server uses the other side of the socket to detect whether the client is still connected, and if that connection is closed it executes the `onDisconnect` handlers for that client.

Comment: Ok, that makes more sense. But what triggers the socket to be open? Is it `firebase.initializeApp(config)`?

Comment: Nope, at that stage there's no knowledge of whether you use the Realtime Database yet. The socket is opened when you first interact with the database, so by reading/writing. It's fairly easy to see this by looking at the WebSocket (`WS`) traffic in the Chrome dev tools.